# Why is intentionally passing any exceptions bad?

Tags: python

I am rewriting an old application from several years ago with the goal of making the code readable and manageable by colleagues (I was away for some time and chaos ensued when others tried to maintain it). I try my hardest to follow the Zen and one of them, as we all know, is "Errors should never pass silently", but alas I do that all the time .. I know, I know... shame... ding ding... shame... ding ding...

Here is a case where I would much rather pass the exception silently with a blanket pass:

```
try:
    with open(self.file_path, "r") as f:
        raw = "".join([next(f) for x in range(100)])
except (IOError, UnicodeDecodeError) as e:
    # No need for logging in this case
    raw = ""
```

I know the example fails if the file is less than 100 lines, but it is more to illustrate a simple point.

My reasoning:

- In this case I just want a blank output (could also have added a user message, but again, just to illustrate a point)
- I initially had IOError as the only exception, but trying to send in a non text-file gave the UnicodeDecodeError, which seems fair enough for some random binary file I tried to break the code with. Now I'm worried some other explicit error might pop up that I haven't tested and that will break the code.
- I really just want the code to try and read a text file and if anything fails, just leave it blank...
  In the olden days I would have just written this:

```
raw = ""
try:
    with open(self.file_path, "r") as f:
        raw = "".join([next(f) for x in range(100)])
except:
    pass
```

Another example:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame()
try:
    if file_type == self.FileTypes.DELIMITED:
        df = pandas.read_csv(self.file_path)
    elif file_type == self.FileTypes.FIXEDWIDTH:
        df = pandas.read_fwf(self.file_path)
    elif file_type == self.FileTypes.MIKE:
        df = mikeio.read(self.file_path).to_dataframe()
except:
    pass
```

A multitude of problems could occur from this. Assume most are acceptable user related "errors", probably something wrong with the file, I'd just handle an empty Pandas dataframe later.

*Please don't burn me for offending the Zen...*

Comment: At the very least you should `except Exception`, not blank. But beyond that… it's up to you. As you say, there may be exceptions you're not thinking of which may break your program in unexpected ways. Are you sure it's okay to hide those errors in all circumstances? That may leave you with hard to debug situations later on.

Comment: Silently ignoring exceptions is generally bad because there will be a situation where an exception is raised for a different reason than what you expected and just discarding the exception leaves you with very little debugging information.

Comment: I think this kind of question is better to be asked in [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).